# How to make post loop in two columns / Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've been trying to split posts for a long time. I tried a variety of variations, but every time I post a single post or copy me all double.
I mean multiple posts.

If anyone has an idea how to fix it I will be very grateful to him.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php do_action( 'esteem_before_post_content' ); ?>
    <?php
        if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $image = '';
            $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'blog-large');
            $title_attribute = the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' );
            $image .= '<figure class="post-featured-image">';
            $image .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="'.the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ).'">';
            $image .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'blog-large', array( 'title' => esc_attr( $title_attribute ), 'alt' => esc_attr( $title_attribute ) ) ).'</a>';
            $image .= '<div class="mask">
                        <div class="image-icon-wrap">
                            <a href="'.$large_image_url[0].'" class="img-icon img-search"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
                            <a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="img-icon img-link"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
            $image .= '</figure>';

            echo $image;
        }
    ?>
    <div class="blog-content">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h2 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2><!-- .entry-title -->
        </header>

        <?php esteem_entry_meta(); ?>

        <div class="entry-content clearfix">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'esteem_after_post_content' ); ?>
</article>
```

**Post loop**

```
<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" class="clearfix">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'navigation', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

If anyone has an idea how to fix it I will be very grateful to him.

Comment: What do you mean by split post, as in display single post in two columns or display multiple posts with few in one column and few in another?

Comment: I mean multiple posts.

Comment: Please post **the loop** as well.

Comment: Done. 
I hope you will help me

Comment: Post in two column <div><article 1><article 2></div><div><article 3><article 4></div>. do you want in this format?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already calling `post_class()` function, you need to pass alternate class to that function itself and make sure to do this only on your custom page or selected blog page. The code will essentially be something like:

```
global $current_class;
$current_class = 'odd'; 
function alternating_post_class ( $classes ) {
    global $current_class;
    if( is_page(<PAGE_ID_HERE>) || is_home() ):
        $classes[] = $current_class;
        $current_class = ($current_class == 'odd') ? 'even' : 'odd';
    endif;
    return $classes;
}
add_filter ('post_class', 'alternating_post_class');
```

This should resolve the problem by giving you **odd/even** class which you can use to style your two columns.

Cheers Mate!!!

Comment: Because I'm a little idiot and I'm not very familiar, where should I put this code?
Thank you again.

Comment: @llamaloverbg This goes in **functions.php** and replace the `<PAGE_ID_HERE>` with the actual page id if you are using a custom page template, if you have just selected a page in **Reading Settings** then remove `is_page(<PAGE_ID_HERE>)  ||` part in if condition.

Comment: Also @llamaloverbg, Kudos on the choice of name!!

Comment: What code did you added? By any chance or accident, did you happen to have written the word video in `is_page()` function without using quote?

Comment: Check my last comment again

Comment: Yeap. I fixed it.

Comment: It was the same as it was at the beginning.

Comment: use the inspector to see if the two consecutive article tags have odd and even classes

Comment: You noticed that your article structure is broken? You need to fix that first.

Comment: Good luck and drop me a message if any other help is needed.